# ZF2 share created Objects

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to know how im able to share a class about my application.

Actually i create a Foo Object within my module.php, set some attributes and want to use this created Foo Class within another class. At the time of the created Foo Object my Bar Object do not exists.

I think i have to use the ServiceManager but i do not know how i have to use him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the object in a factory in Module.php like this:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'My\Foo' =>  function($sm) {
                $foo = new \My\Foo();
                $foo->setAtt('value');
                return $foo;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

and then get it from the service manager, for example from the controller like this:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('My\Foo')
```

Comment: Ok, very nice solution thanx. If i get the Object via the ServiceLocator within my module.php and set for example the Value $foo->setAtt("hello"). and want to get this value within my Bar Object is it possible with $this->getServiceLocator()->get()->getAtt(). I want to be able to access values which is set in another class.